# Kusto KQL equivalent to LIKE CONCAT column with value (mysql)

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to translate the following MySQL (v5.6) query:

```
SELECT name FROM world WHERE capital LIKE CONCAT(name, '%city')
```

into Kusto KQL, but the following doesn't work:

```
world | where capital matches regex strcat(name,".*city") | project name
```

Probably since the the `matches regex` takes only a string value, and `concat(name,".*city")` is a column.

Even the following doesn't work:

```
world | extend a =  strcat(name, ".*City") | where capital matches regex a
```

Any suggestions to how I can translate this query to KQL?

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `matches regex` must be a scalar string constant, and can depend on row context.

If you can make any assumptions on the actual data, you may not need to use a regular expression at all, and have a wide set of string operators to choose from (depending on the data and the requirement, of course): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators

For example:

```
let world = datatable(capital:string)
[
    "Belize City",
    "Jeruslam",
    "Mexico City",
    "Tulum",
    "NotARealCity"
]
;
world
| extend _ends_with = capital endswith "city",
               _has = capital has "city",
          _contains = capital contains "city"
```

Results with:

```
| capital      | _ends_with | _has | _contains |
|--------------|------------|------|-----------|
| Belize City  | 1          | 1    | 1         |
| Jeruslam     | 0          | 0    | 0         |
| Mexico City  | 1          | 1    | 1         |
| Tulum        | 0          | 0    | 0         |
| NotARealCity | 1          | 0    | 1         |
```